# Enough money for Italy tour?

Tags: italy

I plan to spend 2 weeks in Italy. I am estimating what would it cost to visit Florence, Venice, Rome and Sicily while staying at reasonable places (clean, friendly and helpful for a tourist something not luxurious but surely comfortable) and without splurging too much on eating high end. A rough estimate per day would be good to start my research :) Thanks much.

Best,
Omer

Comment: Hi Omer. I would consider editing your question to be more specific. It is largely opinion based at the moment. Italy varies largely with prices depending on time of year of visit, cities visiting, mode of transport etc. It can be done very cheap but it can also be done on a very large budget.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your input. I realize that I missed to mention the time of year which probably would be Sep-Oct. I plan to travel mostly via trains while traveling between cities and using metro/bus/on foot intercity. However I think it is still not enough to fill all the details. All I wanted was to get an idea of something not very high end as well as nothing bare bones either. Thanks

Comment: 100 euro/day won't include travel costs. You don't say how you intend to travel but Venice is a few hours away from Florence which is a few hours away from Rome which is more than a few hours away from Sicily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Italy is not very cheap, but neither is it expensive.

A budget of €20 per day on food should allow you to eat out at a pleasant but low-end place for one meal a day.  €50 per night on hotels should get you something decent.

As a rough estimate, I would suggest that a budget of €100 per day should be enough to cover most of what you suggest.